# How to create extension method like C#

Tags: groovy

I want to attach public method to the class.
This is called [extension method in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods).

```
package extensionMethods

class A {

    def testA() {}

    //def testB() {} Need to add a public method to this class A but we don't have access to the class

}

class B {

    def test() {

        def a = new A();
        a.testA()

        a.testB() //Need to add a public method to the Class A without defining the method in the class A
    }
}

//In C# way -> Extension method
class C {

   /* void testB(this A a) {
    }*/

}
```

How can we achieve the similar approach in Groovy?
In the above example I want to attach method `testB()` to `class A`

Answer (score 0):

You will want something like this:

```
package something

class SomeExtensionClass {
    static void testB(A self) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then your `META-INF/services/org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ExtensionModule` extension descriptor...

```
moduleName=Test module for specifications
moduleVersion=1.0-test
extensionClasses=something.SomeExtensionClass
```

See http://groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html#_extension_modules for more info.